# how to fix foreign key error in laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-7, migrate

I have a order table for my orders, i created this table before, but after some times i have to change my migration.

This is my *orders table* before changes :

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->bigInteger('price');
        $table->enum('status', ['unpaid', 'paid', 'preparation', 'posted', 'recieved', 'canceled']);
        $table->string('tracking_serial')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('quantity');

        $table->primary(['product_id', 'order_id']);
    });
```

And this is *orders table* after changes :

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('address_id');
        $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->bigInteger('price');
        $table->string('post_type');
        $table->enum('status', ['unpaid', 'paid', 'preparation', 'posted', 'recieved', 'canceled']);
        $table->string('tracking_serial')->nullable();

        $table->primary(['user_id', 'address_id']);

        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('quantity');

        $table->primary(['product_id', 'order_id']);
    });
```

as you can see i import 3 new lines in `orders` schema :

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('address_id');
$table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->string('post_type');

$table->primary(['user_id', 'address_id']);
```

But when i want to run `php artisan migrate` i get this error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `shop`.`orders` (errno: 150 "Foreign key 
constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `orders` add constraint 
`orders_address_id_foreign` foreign key (`address_id`) references `addresses` (`id`) on delete 
cascade)
```

Why do I have this error ?

UPDATE :

This is my addresses table :

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('state');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->text('address');
        $table->integer('plaque');
        $table->string('postal');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('address_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('address_id');
        $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['user_id', 'address_id']);

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And order migrate before address.

Comment: where is the migration for 'addresses'?

Comment: The problem is on your `addreses` table, may be you created it later (before migrate the the `orders` table). Or your primary key incorrectly formatted

Comment: @lagbox question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope you have used a migration to change the order table and not just modified the original migration?

this error generally happens for few reasons:

1. the fk field (address_id) and pk field (i.e. address) are not the same type
2. the migration for order is running BEFORE address table (i think unlikely in this case as error would be different)
3. address_id is not nullable (from what i can see) therefore when u create a FK the rows that exist currently wont have a valid FK to address. (so make it nullable)

Comment: yes my order table run befor address table, what can i do

Comment: i run address table before order table and my problem solved. thanks

Comment: @Waltun just follow up - you can just change the timestamp of address migration to be before the order table..

Answer (score 3):

You must first create the table, then create the foreign keys:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('address_id');
        $table->bigInteger('price');
        $table->string('post_type');
        $table->enum('status',['unpaid','paid','preparation','posted', 'recieved', 'canceled']);
        $table->string('tracking_serial')->nullable();
        $table->primary(['user_id', 'address_id']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });


Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```