# how to solve this erorr SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table

Tags: laravel

I have this error when run migration

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `tms-app`.`#sql-1e64_2b` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `projects` add constraint `projects_cout_id_foreign` foreign key (`cout_id`) references `couts` (`id`) on update cascade)

this is projects table:

```
  Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('libelle');
            $table->string('libelle_long');
            $table->string('direction');
            $table->integer('cout_id')->unsigned();
            
            $table->foreign('cout_id')
                ->references('id')->on('couts')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('status')
                ->referenecs('id')->on('statuses')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add migrations of `couts` table

Comment: You need to migrate `couts` table before migrate `projects` table

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this error happens, when we define foreign key and you should use `bigInteger('')` or use `unsignedBigInteger('')`.

Use the code below:

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('libelle');
    $table->string('libelle_long');
    $table->string('direction');

    $table->bigInteger('cout_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('status')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('cout_id')->references('id')->on('couts')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('status')->references('id')->on('statuses')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Note:** In tables `couts` & `statuses` change the id field `$table->increments('id');` to `$table->bigIncrements('id');`

Comment: Not sometimes, this is for 5.8 and above version, you need to change also increments to bigIncrements

Comment: Make sure your user's table migration happen before q&a table because q&a migration file referencing users table so it has to be present. Usually, laravel executes migration files based on the date created so better consider executing user table first and then q&a.

Comment: i have this error `   (SQL: alter table `projects` add constraint `projects_status_foreign` foreign key (`status`) references `statuses` () on delete cascade on update cascade)`

Comment: I have edited the answer, you can see now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62961922/how-to-fix-foreign-key-error-in-laravel-migration

Answer (score 0):

This error should be casuses by the following miss-configuration below I mentioned, be sure all of them to be configured correctly

1: Laravel migration foriegn key should be assgined as bigInteger or unsignedBigInteger
example:
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
or
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();

and for assigning foriegn key attribute you should do
$table->foriegn('user_id')->reference('id')->on('users'); // if you need further attribtute you can chain to this line

2: be sure that the order of migration file is formed correclty because Laravel will migrate table based on timestamp for example if need a foreign key from user table first you need to create user table then the child table the timestamp of users table should be older than child (even 1 second)